# Calling format on String instance

Tags: java

I have been taking a look at java 8 after spending a long time with scala. Being stuck in scala mode as I was hacking around I wrote something like `"# instance_method:%s thread:%d".format(testStr, testNum);"` . Weirdly compiler doesn't complain, even though I cannot find an instance method named "format" in String documentation (turns out I didn't realize the docs for static method were what's relevant here). So the following code:

```
public class Weird{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String testStr = "hmm";
        Long testNum = 7L;
        String weird = "# instance_method:%s thread:%d".format(testStr, testNum);
        String msg = String.format("# static:%s thread:%d", testStr, testNum);
        System.err.println(weird);
        System.err.println(msg);
    }
}
```

gave output:

```
hmm
# static:hmm thread:7
```

So `"# instance_method:%s thread:%d".format(testStr, testNum);` evaluates to `testStr` . I probably doing something dumb, but what's going on here?

Comment: Yeah, hard to find: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-. And it doesn't matter if you call a static method on an instance or on the class itself (the first one is unliked/a code smell, though).

Comment: where is the instance method? public static String format(String format,
                            Object... args)

Comment: @sgldiv No instance method. But Java lets you call `static` methods on instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `static` `format` method in the following expression

```
"# instance_method:%s thread:%d".format(testStr, testNum);
```

i.e. you format `testStr` with arguments `testNum`. Since there is no placeholder in `"hmm"` this simply evaluates to `"hmm"`.

Calling a `static` method using a instance is valid in java, but it should be avoided, since it can easily lead to confusion. The type of the expression is used to determine the method called in this case.